# GHCi linking with cross-calling dynlibs fails on OSX

Tags: macos, haskell, shared-libraries, ghc, haskell-stack

#### Setting

Compiler: GHC 7.10.3

I must use two dynamic libraries (`libpetsc` and `libslepc`), one of which uses functions from the other. When linking my application, I encounter the following error, which mentions one such symbol (`KSPConvergedReasons`). NB. my own code does not use this symbol.

```
user specified .o/.so/.DLL could not be loaded
(dlopen($SLEPC_DIR/arch-darwin-c-debug/lib/libslepc.dylib, 5): Symbol
not found: _KSPConvergedReasons
  Referenced from: $SLEPC_DIR/arch-darwin-c-debug/lib/libslepc.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in $SLEPC_DIR/arch-darwin-c-debug/lib/libslepc.dylib)
```

Surely enough, `nm -u` shows `_KSPConvergedReasons` as an undefined
symbol (see below).
I don't understand the reason of this behaviour since I first compile
with all the relevant PETSc and SLEPc headers and link against both
.dylibs.

NB:

The symbol in question (`KSPConvergedReasons`) does exist in the callee library (`libpetsc`):

```
$ nm ${PETSC_DIR}/${PETSC_ARCH}/lib/libpetsc.3.7.2.dylib | grep KSPConv
000000000110a652 T _KSPConvergedDefault
0000000001109703 T _KSPConvergedDefaultCreate
000000000110b934 T _KSPConvergedDefaultDestroy
0000000001109a96 T _KSPConvergedDefaultSetUIRNorm
000000000110a074 T _KSPConvergedDefaultSetUMIRNorm
000000000106533d T _KSPConvergedLSQR
0000000001743280 D _KSPConvergedReasons
...
```

#### Build + link sequence

Build the C code generated from my own library, which in turn uses headers from the two aforementioned libs:

```
gcc -c -g -w ${SRCDIR}/Internal/InlineC.c -o ${LIBDIR}/InlineC_c.o -I${PETSC_DIR_ARCH}/include -I${PETSC_DIR}/include -I${SLEPC_DIR_ARCH}/include -I${SLEPC_DIR}/include
```

Link :

```
stack exec ghci ${SRCDIR}/Spec.hs ${SRCDIR}/Internal/InlineC.hs  ${LIBDIR}/InlineC_c.o  -- -isrc/ -L${PETSC_DIR_ARCH}/lib -L${SLEPC_DIR_ARCH}/lib -lpetsc -lmpich -lslepc
```

#### Question

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Thank you in advance for any pointers,
Marco

---

Undefined symbols in calling dynlib :

```
$ nm -u libslepc.3.7.1.dylib | grep KSP

_KSPAppendOptionsPrefix
_KSPConvergedReasons
...
```